# Can't upgrade with cdromupgrade 

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.04, alternate

I am try to upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10 using alternative CD. I run this command

```
sudo gksu "sh /media/iso/cdromupgrade"
```

after mounted iso as CD. Its gives this error "An upgrade from 'oneric' to 'precise'"

[image: My error message]

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `sudo do-release-upgrade`?

Comment: Yes, this is a very odd way of doing it Arul. Alternatively, you could just boot a LiveCD and upgrade the current install from the Installer.

Comment: @SirCharlo I tried this command it gives "No new release found"

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards My internet is very slow. That's why using this method

Comment: @Jjed when you do this does it follow the same process as  do-release-upgrade?  I've done it from the CD before and ended up loosing a load of programs. Ive not lost anything with ' do-release-upgrade'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my image carefully. There is a typo in codename oneiric is correct not oneric.

```
sudo gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

and correct this error.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu oneiric"
```

Now everything is working fine.